# ios html5 video mp4

Tags: ios, html5-video

In order to get > 10 minute videos on my app accepted, I need to implement a html5 video in a webview. The video is linking as I can hear the audio but the video is a black screen. The videos are all mp4 and I am using the following html

```
<html><body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;"><video width="480" height="300" controls="controls"><source src="'+video+'" type="video/mp4"></video></body></html>
```

can anyone help me get my imagery viewing?

Comment: when you load the page, I assume you see the play button, is it the movie play button?  Then your clicking it to start the video?  After you click it does it show the movie controls?  How did you make the video?  Does the html that it creates work in safari on the desktop with the correct link?

Comment: it is the movie play button in the center. The video was made in final cut. The container loads in safari but not the video

Answer (score 1):

I am going to guess that it is the video format that is the issue.

Here is what is suported:

**H.264 video up to 720p, 30 frames per second, Main Profile level 3.1**
Audio: AAC-LC up to 160 Kbps, 48kHz, stereo
File types: .m4v, .mp4, and .mov

**MPEG-4 video, up to 2.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second, Simple Profile**
Audio: AAC-LC up to 160 Kbps per channel, 48kHz, stereo
File types: .m4v, .mp4, and .mov

[Miro](http://www.getmiro.com/) might help you out, since it has a "for iphone" option that sets up the video just right.